# Put column names of a data frame as the title of plots of each column

Tags: r, plot, dataframe

I have a data frame with 36 columns and more than 3000 rows. I am using plot function inside a `for loop` to plot graphs of each column. I want the title of the graph to appear as column name. How can I do that?

```
for(i in c(1:36)){
  plot(DowData[,i],type="l",main="colnames(DowData)[i]")
}
```

Comment: I guess you mean "column name as title", "not title as column name" ... Then your code is correct except that you need to erase the parenthesis in the main argument. You don't want to pass the expression `colnames(DowData)[i]`as as string (which you do) but the result of this expression, i.e. the name of the column. So just `colnames(DowData)[i]` without parenthesis.

Comment: @MarkHeckmann Yes, this also worked. I guess I should have played a little with my code. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

Using `lapply` you can loop over columns names:

```
 invisible(lapply(colnames(DowData),function(x){
      plot(DowData[,x],main=x,type="l")
    }))
```

Comment: It worked sir, Thank you very much. Can you tell me why we used invisible function?

Comment: Check out in these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653127/what-does-the-function-invisible-do and http://rfunction.com/archives/799

Answer (score 1):

```
data <- read.csv("sample.csv",header=T,sep=",")
for ( i in seq(1,length( data ),1) ) plot(data[,i],ylab=names(data[i]),type="l")
```

This should Work