# How to use the colnames as main title with loops

Tags: r, database, loops, plot

I have a data frame with 76 columns of an equal number of species, I want to plot in different plots each species using a loop. However, I want to use the colnames to obtain each plot with the name of each species. Someone could help me with my problem.

I use the following expression in the loop:

```
title(main=expression(paste("density of",colnames(df))))
```

I tried with this one:

```
title(main=expression(paste("density of",colnames(df[,i]))))
```

Thank you

Comment: Hi Juan - You need to give us some of your data to work with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Put column names of a data frame as the title of plots of each column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881093/put-column-names-of-a-data-frame-as-the-title-of-plots-of-each-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (i in seq_along(colnames(iris))){
  hist(iris[,i],main=paste("density of",names(iris)[i]))
    }
```