# Rmarkdown converting to pdf: show base hist plot but not the output afterwards

Tags: r, pdf, plot, r-markdown

Below the code for generating a histogram plot with the base plot system in R and converting this via Rmarkdown to a pdf (Latex). I set message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, error=FALSE etc, but still get output from the system. How can I just show the plot??

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "Me"
date: "Tuesday, September 30, 2014"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r,message=FALSE,warning=FALSE,cache.comments=FALSE,error=FALSE,prompt=FALSE}
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
replicate(4,hist(replicate(1000,mean(rnorm(10000,1,10))),col="slateblue4",
             main="Distribution of the Mean",col.main="steelblue4",
             xlab="Mean",ylab="Count"))
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the output that you are getting on your document is neither a warning, a message nor an error. Those stuff printed is a legit (but undesired) output from `replicate()` function.

The easiest way out is wrap up the inconvenient `replicate` (the outer one) with `invisible()` function. This latter in practice, suppress the output of the expression passed to it, resulting in the desired output.

````
```{r,message=FALSE,warning=FALSE,cache.comments=FALSE,error=FALSE,prompt=FALSE}
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
invisible(replicate(4,{hist(replicate(1000,{return(mean(rnorm(10000,1,10)))}),col="slateblue4",
             main="Distribution of the Mean",col.main="steelblue4",
             xlab="Mean",ylab="Count")}))
```
````

refs to `invisible`: [doc](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/invisible) and [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653127/what-does-the-function-invisible-do).

Regards!

Comment: Athos, thanks! That indeed worked. Was not aware of this function. Learnt something new again.