# Different behavior of -> (right-arrow) and <- (left arrow) on a for loop

Tags: r, language-design

[Since R3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35648290/what-value-do-the-loop-functions-return-in-r), a `for` loop returns `NULL` (as documented):

```
x <- for(i in 1:3) {i+1}
x
# NULL
```

However, using the right-arrow assignment, it seems to returns the last value:

```
for(i in 1:3) {i+1} -> x
x
# [1] 4
```

The [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/assignOps.html) doesn't comment on `->`, and [as pointed by Ben Bolker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51547557/3938360), the `->` seems to be converted to `<-` anyway:

```
expression(1 -> x)
# expression(x <- 1)
```

So my questions are:

1. Is this a bug or a misunderstanding?
2. Why would `->` behave differently from `<-` in that case, if they're supposed to be identical?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Really this is more of an issue of parsing I think. The command

```
for(i in 1:3) {i+1} -> x
```

actually is parsed to something like

```
for(i in 1:3) {
   x <- {i+1}
}
```

You can kind of see that in the AST with the help of the `lobstr` package

```
lobstr::ast(for(i in 1:3) {i+1} -> x)
o-`for` 
+-i 
+-o-`:` 
| +-1 
| \-3 
\-o-`<-` 
  +-x 
  \-o-`{` 
    \-o-`+` 
      +-i 
      \-1
```

So the assignment is part of the loop body. For example you can also run this without error

```
for(i in 1:3) {i+1} ^2
```

or see what you get from this expression

```
for(i in 1:3) {i+1} + {print(i)}
# [1] 1
# [1] 2
# [1] 3
```

The loop body expression doesn't terminate at the end of the first brace. It ends at the end of the line (or you could make it end with a `;` or by nesting it in a code block). This isn't unique to the assignment operators in any way.

So this isn't a bug, it's just a bit of confusing syntax. What you were expecting would look more like

```
{for(i in 1:3) {i+1}} -> x
```

which still returns NULL.